# How can change shell for a user via ansible?

Tags: linux, shell, ansible

I have some ansible playbook:

```
---
- hosts: servers
  gather_facts: false
  become: yes
  ignore_errors: yes
  tasks:
  - include_vars: users.yml

  - name: Check that user exists
    shell: "grep -q {{item.username}} /etc/passwd"
    ignore_errors: yes
    with_items: "{{ users }}"
    register: userexist

  - name: Block user
    user:
      name: "{{ item.username }}"
      shell: /bin/false
    when: userexist is succeeded
    with_items: "{{ userexist.results }}"
```

And the playbook works correctly, but when a user isn't present in the file /etc/passwd, playbook skips the task "Block user", because gets "rc": 1.
How can ignore "rc": 1 correctly and run the task "Block user", when user isn't present?

Comment: Why (and how) do you want to set a shell for a user that doesn't exist?

Comment: No, i want to skip a user if he isn't present in /etc/passwd. Because in my file users.yml i have users which don't exist on one server but exist other server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to make sure that both tasks are run together for every entry of your list. Currently only one username from the first task will be used in the second.

Theoretically this would be ideal for [a block](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html), but you can't combine a block with a loop. To work around this, you can move the actual tasks in another .yml file that you include:

playbook.yml:

```yml
---
- hosts: servers
  gather_facts: false
  become: yes
  vars:
    users:
      - blah: blubb
        username: nagios
      - blubb: bleh
        username: foobar
  tasks:
  - name: set shell
    include_tasks: set_shell.yml
    loop: "{{ users }}"
```

set_shell.yml

```yml
---
- name: Check that user exists
  shell: "grep -q {{ item.username }} /etc/passwd"
  ignore_errors: yes
  register: userexist
- name: Block user
  user:
    name: "{{ item.username }}"
    shell: /bin/false
  when: userexist is succeeded
```

This will run both tasks sequentially for each user in your list.